# magento2 registration php

Tags: magento2, module, theme, zend-framework

What is the difference between a THEME And Module in Magento 2 ?

**Theme Registration.php**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'Inchoo_Helloworld',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Module Registration.php**

```
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::Module,
```

Comment: you want to know difference between theme or module ? or need to know difference between there registration.php file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To register the module, you need to create a registration.php file with the following content:**

> app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[VendorName]_[ModuleName]',
    __DIR__
);
```

**To register your theme in the system, in your theme directory you need to create a registration.php file with the following content:**

> app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[themename]/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/[VendorName]/[themename]',
    __DIR__
);
```